# Sorting by title of a referenced entity instead of ID

Tags: views

On a view, I have a content type "A" that references another content type "B".

Content "B" has, for eg, the following records:

ID 1: Title "AAA"
ID 2: Title "CCC"
ID 3: Title "BBB"

I would like, inside the view of content type "A", to sort by the Title of content type "B". As it works out of the box, afaik, the records will be sorted by ID, thus being displayed on a table like this:

AAA
CCC
BBB

but I would like to sort them alphabetically by title.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to sort inside the view of content type "A", to sort by the Title of content type "B":

- Take relationship of "Content type B" field for eg:
  **Content referenced from field_name**(reference field name of content type B inside content type A)
- In sort criteria > add title field , then from "**Relationship**" drop-down select "**field name**" that added in first step
- In Order select **"ascending order"** & save the view

Comment: Thank you. Thats's the principle - you want the title and then, on the relationship, you specify the related content for it.